# Google Sheets- Formula to get a cell value using the value from another cell as the row number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to get the value from a cell using the value from another cell as the row number. Example: let’s say cell B2 has a value of 12. I need to get the value of cell D12 - but while I know the column of the cell I want to get the value from, the row has to come from cell B2. So I’d use a formula like =D(value(B2)) - only that doesn’t work. If B2 has a value of 17, then my formula would retrieve the value of D17, etc. I’ve tried every way I can think of to do this but no joy. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Use the INDEX function.

```cpp
=INDEX(D:D,B2)
```

Comment: Sorry! I totally forgot to mention that the cell I’m trying to get the value from is on a different sheet. Neither OtherWorksheet!INDEX(D:D,B2) nor OtherWorksheet!index(“D”&B2) work.

Comment: Use `=INDEX(OtherSheet!D:D,B2)`

Answer (score 0):

`=indirect("OtherWorksheet!D"&B2)`

Comment: Sorry! I totally forgot to mention that the cell I’m trying to get the value from is on a different sheet. Neither OtherWorksheet!INDEX(D:D,B2) nor OtherWorksheet!index(“D”&B2) work.

Comment: Try the edited answer.